# Where can I find New York state probate records after the 1920s?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, probate-records

FamilySearch has [New York probate records](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/1920234) for county courts but "most records end in the 1920s." I'm particularly interested in [Montgomery county](https://familysearch.org/search/image/index#uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffamilysearch.org%2Frecapi%2Fsord%2Fwaypoint%2F9V9R-GPK%3A213300301%3Fcc%3D1920234) where FamilySearch only has records through 1922. Where can I find probate records for the succeeding years?

Comment: We _hope_ the records don't end in 1922. I know what you meant, but could you edit your question please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probate records for New York State are kept by the Surrogate's Court in each county.  The website of the [New York State Unified Court System](http://www.nycourts.gov/courthelp/goingtocourt/records.shtml) says:

> **Genealogy Research**
>   Since 1787, probate records like wills are filed
>   and kept by the Surrogate's Court in each county. These records are
>   available from the courthouse and appointments may be needed to view
>   the records. There may be a fee to access some of the records. Use the
>   Court Locator box to find the Surrogate's Court in the county you're
>   interested in.

Addresses for [Montgomery County](http://www.nycourts.gov/courts/4jd/montgomery/index.shtml) can be found via the county court locator for the [Surrogate's Courts Outside New York City](http://www.nycourts.gov/courts/cts-outside-nyc-SURROGATES.shtml). Unlike some other county courts in New York State, there does not appear to be an online genealogy guide for the Montgomery County Surrogate's Court.

The [Probate Record Pathfinder](http://www.archives.nysed.gov/a/research/res_tools_nysa_path_probate.shtml) at the New York State Archives gives an overview of the process plus some information about the (limited) records held at the archives.  They say:

> The Surrogate’s Courts do not accept email requests for research
>   assistance. The preferred method of inquiry is in writing via U.S.
>   Mail. Frame such requests in succinct and specific terms, stating name
>   of decedent and date of death. Applicable search, copying, and
>   authentication fees may be charged. Researchers should keep in mind
>   that in all time periods, many people died without wills, and there
>   may have been no court-supervised distribution of their estates.
>
> More recent records relating to the estates of persons who died
>   without a will (intestate) are found in the Surrogate's Court. In such
>   cases, the court appoints an administrator, whose duties are similar
>   to those of an executor, and distribution of the property to heirs is
>   made according to state law. In instances when an executor declines to
>   assume responsibility, a “renunciation” is made, and the court
>   appoints an administrator.

New York State also provides an online copy of the [Freedom of Information Law](http://www.dos.ny.gov/coog/foil2.html) which describes the rules governing public access to records, and the fees authorized for making copies of the records.

The FamilySearch Wiki article on [Montgomery County](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Montgomery_County,_New_York_Genealogy) gives links to the collections you've already checked (which stop in 1922) and notes:

> Additional Probate Indexes and Abstracts
>
> Additional probate indexes or abstracts can sometimes be found using
>   search phrases such as Montgomery County, New York Genealogy probate
>   wills in online catalogs like WorldCat or the FamilySearch Catalog.

Also, one caution: not all probate files on FamilySearch are in a database with the word "probate" in the title.  See [Using a card index to find Probate records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/6660/1006) for an example from New York City, where probate records appear in a mixed batch of court records.

For the most up-to-date information, it may be worthwhile to consult Chapter 6 in the New York Genealogical & Biographical Society's new publication, [New York Family History Research Guide and Gazetteer](http://newyorkfamilyhistory.org/global/store/new-york-family-history-research-guide-and-gazetteer).

Comment: I sent out a letter the day I asked this question (3 weeks ago). Still no reply. Snail mail isn't that slow. Maybe they have a lot of work and not enough hands to do it.

Comment: This week I received an email stating that my documents were mailed. The email also contained a PDF of the documents. That's 7 weeks from the time I sent the letter.